# Keycloak: providing user attribute on register (manual registration and register from IdP)

Tags: keycloak, idp

I currently have customized registration form through templating in keycloak to add user information, through a form.

However, I'd like to provide user the same form when authenticating from an external IdP.

How can I do that with as little duplication as possible?